# iOS UISegmentedControl opens sans font not applying?

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol, uifont

I try to apply `opensans-regular` font to segmented control title. But it is behaving Abnormal. Can't we apply `opensans` font to `UISegmentedControl`?

Here is my code

```
hmSegmentControl.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor],NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Regular" size:13]};
hmSegmentControl.selectedTitleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor],NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Regular" size:13]};
```

Comment: Please share your code, how you are trying to apply font.

Comment: Is this font included in the project?? is the font working on a UILabel or any other UI control??

Comment: Yes, font files were included. They are working on labels from XIB. Not working programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Issue got fixed. For OpenSans-Regular font, we have to give font name as @"OpenSans" But not @"OpenSans-Regular".